# fit a line of the form $y=ax$ through those points

Tags: calculus, functions

Suppose that some experiment produces the following data points: 
$$(1,5),(2,5),(3,10),(4,13),(5,9)$$
We want to fit a line of the form $y=ax$ through those points. The error  (which of course depends on the choice of $a$ ) that our fit makes at every input location $x$, is measured by the following error criterion: $$((ax−y)^2)⋅\log(((ax−y)^2)+1),$$
where obviously the $\log$ is the natural logarithm.
Now, let the function $E:a↦E(a)$ be the total error overall points, depending on the parameter $a$.

Find the minimum value that $E$  attains, to three decimals accuracy behind the decimal point:

Comment: Looks like homework. What have you tried?

Comment: i am not sure where to start with it, maybe take the derivative of the function and substitute the points into it?

Answer (score 0):

If you use the normal least square fit, you minimize
$$F(a)=\sum_{i=1}^5 (ax_i-y_i)^2$$ which corresponds to the linear regression with no intercept. So, for this case, the formula is
$$a=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^5 x_i y_i}{\sum_{i=1}^5 x_i^2}=\frac{142}{55}\approx 2.58182$$ and this is more than likely a good estimate for the minimization of
$$G(a)=\sum_{i=1}^5 (ax_i-y_i)^2\log\big((ax_i-y_i)^2+1 \big)$$ Since you want to minimize $G$, you need its derivative equal to zero. Differentiating, we have
$$H(a)=\frac {dG(a)}{da}=\sum_{i=1}^5 \Big( \frac{2 x_i (a x_i-y_i)^3}{(a x_i-y_i)^2+1}+2 x_i (a x_i-y_i) \log \left((a x_i-y_i)^2+1\right)\Big)$$ for which you need a numerical method such as Newton.
The iterates being given by
$$a_{n+1}=a_n-\frac{H(a_n)}{H'(a_n)}$$ If you are patient you could establish the formula for $H'(a)$ but this would be quite tedious. So, use numerical derivatives and write
$$a_{n+1}=a_n-\frac{2\,\epsilon\, H(a_n)}{H(a_n+\epsilon)-H(a_n-\epsilon)}$$ with, for example $\epsilon=10^{-3}a_n$.

Using $a_0=\frac{142}{55}$, the first iterate will be $a_1=2.52038$ and continuing 
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & a_n \\
 0 & 2.58182 \\
 1 & 2.52038 \\
 2 & 2.52035 
\end{array}
\right)$$ which clearly shows that, for the resuired accuracy, one single iteration is more that sufficient.